# Patenting Products in Other Countries

Tags: international

I'm a start-up and I want to patent my products or apps and post it on the google play and app store. I already asked my friend who took law. She said that my app should and can be patented. I don't live either in U.S or U.K. I only know how to patent my apps in my country. How can I protect my apps outside of my country? How much does it cost to patent an idea in another country?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for international coverage, there are several options, including:

- Filing in a specific country or countries. Check out [35 U.S.C. 119](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/35/119), if you plan to file in the U.S.
- Filing a [Patent Cooperation Treaty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patent_Cooperation_Treaty) (PCT) application.

This answer doesn't cover all options and each option provides you with a different filing date. As always, talk to a patent professional in your targeted country or countries.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you do not need to be a resident of the US or other country to file there. By international treaties a country can't treat domestic applicants different from foreign applicants. In the US an initial filing can be done in any language.